# How to mount a DB-9 adapter to an enclosure

Tags: serial, connector, rs232, modbus, db9

I have a DB-9 connector that needs to be mounted to an electronics enclosure. This hole for the DB-9 connector will be manually cut out.

**Question:** How can the DB-9 connector be secured to the enclosure?

I am using [the following DB-9 connector](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01H46DDW4). I need a DB9-to-DB9 connector, not DB9 connector on one side, and some other pins on the other side. Is there a better variant of it that has mounting screws or something?

[image]

Comment: Those are inline cable adapters and aren't intended to be mounted in a housing.  Why are you using one of those?  You can't solder anything to it inside the housing, you would have to connect a DB9 cable to it inside your housing.

Comment: @JRE My board inside the housing has a DB9 connector, and I think it is better to use a first DB9 cable to connect the board's DB9 to a DB9 inline cable adapter mounted on the housing, then a second DB9 cable to connect from the housing inline adapter to the PC.

Comment: @JRE `[PC's DB9 Port]` ---- `[ inline connector on housing ]` ----- `[Board's DB9 port]`

Comment: Usually those stand-off style clamp nuts can be removed and reinserted from the outside of the plate with the connector on the rear of the plate provided the plate thickness itself is not too large. You will need the appropriate sized nut driver.

Answer (score 3):

Those look like they are designed to join two cables together, not in a box or anything, just cable to cable.

Look for a *bulkhead* or *panel* mount connector or *feedthrough*. You might also be able to buy a panel-mount connector and short serial cable in one piece, sometimes called a *panel-mount serial extension* or similar.

You might have difficulty finding something at your usual supplier, as it's actually quite unusual to use a DB-9 cable inside the case of an appliance.  More usual is to have a DB-9 cable outside, and something cheaper, smaller and more flexible inside - such as a ribbon cable.

Comment: If I get [this bracket panel providing a DB9 to IDC (2x5 female) connection](https://www.amazon.com/SinLoon-Bracket-Extension-Adapter-Motherboard/dp/B01M2921NI) how should I connect 2 wires to the IDC female connector? Is there a IDC (2x5 male) connector with screwterminals on the other end to securely accept wires?

Comment: Or will something like [2X5 10P Dual Rows 2.54mm Shrouded IDC Male Header](https://www.amazon.com/Accessories-10-Pack-2-54mm-Shrouded-Connectors/dp/B00B3PI02G) do the trick, assuming the pitch is the same? I assume I will insert the wires with ends stripped into the shrouded connector and close the connector.

Comment: @Nyxynyx Not to answer your question but when using IDC connectors, you do not strip the wires. The connector is designed to cut through the insulation. IDC = Insulation Displacement Connector.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps there are some nuances I've missed here, but if not then:-

1. Look at your [example](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01M2921NI) and do the same - simply remove the supplied screws and replace with longer ones and bolt through the enclosure.  You can also get [long versions](http://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/connector-screws-nuts/8277245/)  of hex ended screws like these.
2. Don't use screws.  Glue it to the enclosure with something like epoxy or hot glue.  If the enclosure wall is too thick to allow the exterior connector to mate, glue the adaptor with the bulk of it on the outside rather than the inside.

Wacky idea.  Does it need a connector at all?  There is also the possibility of connecting a cable only to the internal DB-9 connector.  Then simply feed the cable through the enclosure wall.  Figure out some form of strain relief.  You're then free to do what ever you want at the loose end.  No one said that equipment can't have a flying lead.  Most of it used to, and this is sometimes a practical solution.

Comment: Just noticed that replacing with longer versions of the screws may just work! Thanks wil ltry that out!

Answer (score 0):

The devices you have pictured are gender changers and not intended for the use you are looking for.  They will work for your application but, you will also need to be creative, which is why I believe you should use a DB9 that has solder pins on one side.  Wire what ever you have in your enclosure directly to the solder side of the DB9. If that is not possible, make a short cable inside your enclosure. Be mindful of your connecting cable, if it is a null cable then make sure your internal cable is a straight through of you will cancel the null of the external serial cable.